# PHP code to modify a URL

Tags: php, javascript

My current code is:

```
$scripturl.'main.php?i='.$app_id.'&s='.$app_secret."&n=".$n, 'response_type' => 'code'));
```

I want to add `&display=touch` to the end of the result URL, like so:

```
status_update%2Cuser_birthday%2Cpublish_stream&response_type=code&display=touch
```

If I add it in the above code like this: `'response_type' => 'code&display=touch'`

The result URL shows up like this:

```
status_update%2Cuser_birthday%2Cpublish_stream&response_type=code%26display%3Dtouch
```

It converted `&` to `%26` and `=` to `%3D`. How do i add `&display=touch` without triggering that effect?

Comment: Your post is nearly impossible to read. Please re-read the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format the post legibly.

Answer (score 1):

Add `'display' => 'touch'` as another element in the array:

```
$scripturl.'main.php?i='.$app_id.'&s='.$app_secret."&n=".$n, 'response_type' => 'code', 'display' => 'touch'));
```